# getChildren method is missing from class ScrollPane in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

When tried to use following code, an exception java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException occurred:

```
ScrollPane scrollPaneIdFx = new ScrollPane();
ImageView imageViewIdFx = new ImageView();
scrollPaneIdFx.getChildrenUnmodifiable().add(imageViewIdFx);
```

and if trying to use below code then getChildren is not visible due to protected specifier

```
ScrollPane scrollPaneIdFx = new ScrollPane();
ImageView imageViewIdFx = new ImageView();
scrollPaneIdFx.getChildren().add(imageViewIdFx);
```

Can someone one suggest, how to add children to ScrollPane?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `ScrollPane` stores its single child in the [`contentProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#contentProperty):

> The node used as the content of this ScrollPane.

Therefore corrected code is:

```
scrollPaneIdFx.setContent(imageViewIdFx);
```

In case of you would like to store multiple `Node`s in a `ScrollPane` the `contentProperty` should be set to one of the containers (`Parent` object) then the `Node`s should be added to this container.

Answer (score 1):

There is only a single "child" you should add to a `ScrollPane`: the [`content`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ScrollPane.html#contentProperty). If you want a `ScrollPane` that contains multiple `Node`s, add them to a suitable `Parent` (e.g. a `Pane`) and use this `Parent` as content of the `ScrollPane`.

Example

```
VBox content = new VBox();
content.getChildren().add(child1);
content.getChildren().add(child2);
...
scrollPane.setContent(content);
```